# Pegar id do usuario por SESSION

Tags: php, session

Estou com uma duvida , como eu pego o id do rapaz que efetuou login no meu sistema? Para que posteriormente ele possa alterar seus dados.

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_POST ["loginUsuario_externo"])){
        include_once("../controllers/Usuario_Externo_Controller.php");
        $usuario_externo = new Usuario_externo_Controller;
        $usuario_externo->login();
    }
```

Funçao login

```
public function login() {

    $this->usuario_externos->email($this->input->get('email'))
                           ->senha($this->input->get('senha'));

    $resultado = $this->usuario_externos->login();


    if($resultado) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['login'] = $resultado;
      echo '<script>window.location = "../views/externo/";</script>';
      echo ('Aguarde, redirecionando.');
    } else {
        echo ('E-mail ou Senha incorreto(os).');
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
  public function login() {

    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha AND status = 1 LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $this->senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetch();

}
```

starta sessão e vrf se há sessao

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  function session_checker(){
    if (! isset($_SESSION['login'])){
      header ("Location:../");
      exit(); 
    }
  }
  session_checker();
  ?>
```

Comment: <?php
if (isset ($_POST ["loginUsuario_externo"])){
  include_once("../controllers/Usuario_Externo_Controller.php");
  $usuario_externo = new Usuario_externo_Controller;  
  $usuario_externo->login();

}

Comment: eu tentei 
`$codigo = mysql_query("SELECT u.id, u.nome FROM usuario_externos u WHERE u.nome = '" . $_SESSION['nome'] . "';"); 
echo mysql_result($codigo, 0);`

Comment: deixa ver se entendi, você quer armazenar na sessão esse ID do usuário vindo do banco, e depois recuperar essa sessão com o ID pra alteração dos dados ?

Comment: isso :) mas nao esta dando certo de jeito algum

Comment: Você precisa editar a pergunta e colocar o código que inicia a sessão e faz o login.  a gente não sabe o que `login()` faz, nem se vc fez a atribuição em `$_SESSION` ou se iniciou a sessão no outro arquivo.

Comment: Eu não entendi o que essa linha faz,    `$this->usuario_externos->email($this->input->get('email'))
                           ->senha($this->input->get('senha'));` você esta passando uma senha por get? no login do seu model veja se email e senha tem algum valor.

Comment: sim eles estao vindo da view , atraves do get

Comment: `print_r($stmt->fetch())` exibe algo? no bind do email, mude : `PDO::PARAM_INT` para `PDO::PARAM_STR` ou deixe sem nada.

Comment: tipo se eu colocasse no controller $id=$_SESSION['id']; era pra pegar a carniça do id ? ou nao?

Comment: `print_r($stmt->fetch())` trouxe `stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [nome] => marcus [cpf] => [email] => a@a.com [perfil] => 1 [senha] => 6fab33feda475044 [status] => 1 [instituicao_ext] => unie )`

Comment: Sim é para pegar o id, deve ser `$_SESSION['login']['id']` na dúvida de um `print_r($_SESSION)`.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\portoaberto\app\controllers\Usuario_Externo_Controller.php on line 45` PQ???? ehwaaeauw só da erro ahweauw

Comment: Mude, para `$_SESSION['login']->id`, caso queira acessar como um array, faça `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: rray vc e o bixao vei *----------------* poe ai nas respostas que deu certo *--*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema parece ser o acesso a sessão, pelos comentário foi visto que o retorno do `login()` model retornar um objeto e jogava ele na sessão ele deveria ser acessado assim `$_SESSION['login']->id`.

Caso deseja acessar as informações do usuário na sessão como um array, define o tipo de retorno no `fetch()`. `return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

NÃO passe informaçãoes sensiveis como uma senha pelo método get, pois ela ficará visivel na url, práticamente você oferece o ouro ao bandido.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu um grande impedimento para o meu projeto .

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta maneira, utilizando o session_id()

```
<?php
session_start();
$r=session_id();

echo "o id da sessão é: ".$r;

?>
```

Comment: eu tentei isso , porem ele aparece o id da sessão e nao do usuario que logou na sessão.