# Como pegar o ID do usuário Logado na sessão em PHP e jogar em uma variável para fazer inserção?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso pega o ID do usuário já logado para jogar em uma query de insert, por que irei liga-la a uma Foreign key de Funcionarios. Preciso pegar essa ID, só que não estou sabendo como proceder e sou iniciante no php.

Script de login:

```
<?php
SESSION_start();
include('conexao.php');

if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string(conexao(), $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string(conexao(), ($_POST['senha']));

$query = "select * from funcionarios where login='{$usuario}' and senha = '{$senha}'";

$result = mysqli_query(conexao(), $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$error = "Usuário ou Senha incorretos";

if ($row > 0) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
    header('Location: paginaConsulta.php');
    exit();
} else {
    unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
    $_SESSION["invalido"] = $error;
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Parte do insert:

```
//Caso não ocorra nenhum erro, permita que os dados sejam inseridos no banco.
  if ($row == 0) {
    $link = conexao();

    $query = "insert into clientes(nome_cliente, cnpj)
    values('{$nome_cliente}', '{$cnpj}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    //Recupero o id do cliente que acabou de ser inserido

    $idCliente = mysqli_insert_id($link);

      //Recupero o id do funcionaio que acabou de ser inserido

    $idFuncionario = $_SESSION["usuario"];

    $query2 = "insert into erros(tipo_erro,solucao,data_ocorrencia,sistema, Fk_Funcionarios, Fk_Clientes)
    values('{$nome_erro}', '{$solucao}', '{$data}', '{$sistema}', '{$idFuncionario}', '{$idCliente}')";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);
    }


  header('location: paginaConsulta.php');
}
```

Como declaro uma sessão nova para puxar o ID? Estou enviando o formulário via post, e o ID está em AUTO INCREMENT no banco de dados.

Eu não sei como recuperar o ID do usuário logado na sessão para eu poder jogar nessa variável de $IdFuncionario.

A parte de idClientes ta funcionando.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar id do usuario por SESSION](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95341/pegar-id-do-usuario-por-session)

Comment: O que a função `conexao` faz? Se ela retorna uma conexão com o banco tem muita coisa que pode melhorar no código.

Comment: Consegui resolver, com a solução dos companheiros abaixo. O que eu poderia melhorar no código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($row > 0) {

    $dados_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dados_usuario['id'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
    header('Location: paginaConsulta.php');
    exit();
}
```

Modifique o seu `if` para este acima.

Obs1: para recuperar o `id` do usuário depois basta acessar `$_SESSION['id_usuario']`.

Obs2: Estou considerando que o campo `id` no seu banco de dados esteja escrito exatamente desta forma (letras minúsculas), caso seja diferente, fazer a modificação no código.

Comment: Deu certo! Após ter conseguido puxar o id do usuário logado na sessão, eu consegui resolver meu problema e jogar essa sessão em outra variável que será requisita pelo INSERT. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte:

```
//seu código...
$result = mysqli_query(conexao(), $query);
$arrayResutado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //Vai te retornar um array, com os retornos do banco para o select que você fez, o qual provavelmente tem o id que vc precisa...
if ($row > 0) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
    $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $arrayResultado['usuario_id']; // Dentro das [''] você coloca identico ao campo no banco de dados;
    header('Location: paginaConsulta.php');
    exit();
} else {
    unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
    unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
    $_SESSION["invalido"] = $error;
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver. Anotei sua solução para estudos.